# Export iggrid With Grouping feature to Excel

Tags: javascript, infragistics

I am using IgGrid from Infragistics to generate a grid

This Grid I am using Grouping with summary feature

Can anyone help me how to Export this grid to Excel

I have tried to use export to excel feature from Infragistics but this feature its reading data from server-side and grouping feature in grid its a client-side